# long press search key to open app, android

Tags: android, search, key

I have an app, an search app.
Now I have a question, when you are on your homescreen for example and you long press the search key, it open Google search.
How can you set an code in the app, that when you long press the search key, it open my app?

I hope you understand me, and I hope you could help me.

Gaauwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these links, It gives the sample to open Search key.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Comment: Well I'm just starter whitch developing of Android apps, so with code must I specific use, maybe you can post the code here?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do with the Search button:

1. Open an internal search for your App data when you App is running and on top
2. Run your App when you long press the search button at any moment even when you are on other apps.

For the first option see the links provided by Abhi:
 http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html
 http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

For the second option, which I understand that is what you wanted to do, you have to add to your Androidmanifest.xml the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Independently to these two options, another thing you may be interested in, is to add your App data to the global search (quick search box), like a dictionary App would do:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:label="@string/search_label"
       android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/settings_description"
       android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
       android:searchSuggestAuthority="dictionary"
       android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW">
</searchable>
```